# Figuring out why Word Counter program output is 0 or 1

Tags: c++

I need to figure out a bug with my program. When I type **Hello World I am**, it should count the number of spaces, but I keep getting **0** or **1**. Below is my full program:

```
    #include "windows.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cctype>
    using namespace std;

    //Global declarations.

    //Function prototypes.
    void pause();
    void numWords(string&);
    int numWords(char []);

    int main()
    {
        string userVal;
        numWords(userVal);
        char *conStr= new char[userVal.length()];
        strcpy(conStr, userVal.c_str()); //String converted to a C-string.
        int fin= numWords(conStr);
        cout<< "The number of words in the sentence is "<< fin<< "."<< endl;
        delete[] conStr;
        conStr= 0;

        pause();
        return 0;
}
/***************************************FUNCTIONS**********************************************************************/
/*1st function to pause the program.*/
void pause()
{
    cin.sync();
    cin.ignore();
}

/*2nd function to ask the user for input. OP*/
void numWords(string &len)
{
    cout << "Please enter a sentence and I will tell you how many words it has: " << endl;
    cin >> len;
}

/*3rd function to count the number of total spaces in the sentence.*/
int numWords(char usStr[])
{
    int wrdCount= 0,
        chrCount= 0,
        index= 0;
    while(usStr[index]!= '\0')
    {
        if(isspace(usStr[index]))
        {
            if(chrCount)
            {
                wrdCount++;
                chrCount= 0;
            }
        }
        else
            chrCount++;
        index++;

    }
    if(chrCount)
        wrdCount++;
    return wrdCount;
}
```

Can anyone please explain why it doesn't count the spaces, or if I need another loop mechanism to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `getline` because `cin` will stop after the first whitespace, so it will only grab the first word.

Comment: Getline only works with chars. How will that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoryKramer's suggestion was correct. `cin` will stop after the first whitespace. If you want to read a whole line, you use `getline`. I've made changes to your code to show this as well as renamed the function you use to get the sentence from the user. Also, you don't have to convert to a c-style string for this to work, a string works just fine.

```
//Function prototypes.
void pause();
void getSentence(string&);
int numWords(string&);

int main()
{
    string userVal;
    getSentence(userVal);

    int fin = numWords(userVal);
    cout << "The number of words in the sentence is " << fin << "." << endl;

    pause();
    return 0;
}

void getSentence(string &len)
{
    cout << "Please enter a sentence and I will tell you how many words it has: " << endl;
    getline(cin, len);
}

int numWords(string& usStr)
{
    int wrdCount = 0,
        chrCount = 0,
        index = 0;
    while(index < usStr.length())
    {
        ...
    }
    if(chrCount)
        wrdCount++;
    return wrdCount;
}
```

You also probably want to `#include <string>`

Comment: Thank you Frank and Cory for the suggestion. By modifying the cin to a getline it worked like a charm. Can you explain why because I thought that  by using cin it was going to do the work ok?

Comment: cin extraction stops as soon as it reaches a whitespace. With your input, "Hello World I am", only the first word, "Hello" is read and the rest remain in the input stream. With the overload of getline used, everything is read until a newline, '\n', is reached or end-of-file (EOF)